# How to get mongodb version in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

We create new collection in javascript on the server side with:
**Questions = new Mongo.Collection('questions');**

Just like above, in 'Mongo' class, is there such method like Mongo.getVersion() or Mongo.version() which returns the mongodb version like **db.version()** executed from shell?

I want to run text search in mongodb. But depending on the version, the search syntax is different.
For example, in mongodb 2.6 or above, 
**Questions.find({ $text: { $search: searchValue } });**
Whereas in mongodb 2.4, the equivalent would be:
**db.questions.runCommand("text", { search: searchValue });**

So i want to check the version first and then execute different fetch functions above.

Answer (score 0):

From the "version" field from a document that the db.serverStatus() command returns.

Comment: how to get the same value in javascript, not mongo shell? I want it in server side publications.

Comment: db.serverStatus().version

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version using this:

var getMongodbVersion = require('get-mongodb-version');
getMongodbVersion(opts, function done (err, version) { })
getMongodbVersion(opts, callback)

opts

opts - mongodb.Db If opts is the result of require('mongodb').connect(function(err, db){}), the version will be pulled from db.admin().serverInfo().version

path - File Path to mongod

path - mongodb uri

callback

err - Error Contains errors if any.

version - String The version discovered.

More info could be obtained from: 
https://github.com/mongodb-js/get-mongodb-version

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am looking for builtin meteor function to achieve it. I don't want to add extra packages just to get the version.